# Threejs Mesh scaling to renderer and not preserving aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using [STLLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html) plugin from threejs github

this is my code snippet

```
this.loadSTL = function(scene, stlFile){
      var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
      loader.addEventListener('load', function(geometry, materials){
        var geometry = geometry.content;
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ambient: 0xff5533, color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200});
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        mesh.position.set(0, -0.9, 0);
        mesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
        mesh.scale.set( 0.012, 0.012, 0.012);

        scene.add(mesh);
      });
      loader.load(stlFile);
    }
```

the problem here is the object I load through stl file increases/decreases in height based on the window resolution. is there something we need to set to keep width/height of the mesh constant and not varying with the screen/window resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should handle window resize event and do the following:

```
function OnResize ()
{
    camera.aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix ();
    renderer.setSize (canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `camera.aspect = 1` solved the problem. the correct solution would be setting

```
camera.aspect = $container.width/$container.height
```